# Design a button with Image on top of Title

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uibutton

In order to make my buttons big and square rahter than rectangle, so that they are easier to touch, I want to display the Image on top of the Title, and not on the left.

I can't see any option in Interface Builder 3.2.4 to do  that.

Is there any trick to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround. Since there is not the option for positionning the image relatively from the text, i did as follows:

Property LineBreaks:

- Clip

Property Content:

- H. Alignment: Left
- V. Alignment: Middle

Property "Title Edge Insert" of the button:

- Left:    31
- Top:    -15
- Right:    0
- Bottom:   0

Property "Image Edge Insert" of the button:

- Left:   -20
- Top:     35
- Right:    0
- Bottom:   0

You probably need to adjust the values depending on the size of your button, your image and your test...

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep a imageView with your image and add that imageview as your subview to the button.

Comment: I am not sure I understand, can you describe the steps in more details in IB?